# How to check column value on insert trigger like Update trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a update trigger for update status column value change and update other table record and it is working fine. Here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON [dbo].[recharge_request]

FOR UPDATE
    AS

    DECLARE @status varchar(50);

    SELECT @status=i.status FROM inserted i; 

    IF UPDATE (status)
        BEGIN
            IF @status='Failure'
                --My Update Statement
            ELSE IF @status='Success'
                --My Update Statement
        END
```

Now I'm want to create an insert trigger also for check status column value and perform other table operation. because in some case status column value will not been update to I need to perform some operation on insert if column value is '`Success`' or '`Fail`'. status column possible values are '`Success`', '`Fail`', '`Pending`' and '`Process`'. any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Issue has been resolved here is solution:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterInsert] ON [dbo].[recharge_request]
AFTER INSERT
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @status varchar(50);

            SELECT @status=i.status FROM inserted i; 

            IF @status='Success'
                BEGIN
                    --My Update statement
                END
        END
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> DECLARE @status varchar(50);
>
> SELECT @status=i.status FROM inserted i;
> ```

you are not handling cases where multiple rows are being updated.

You need to treat the `inserted` and `deleted` as a table that may contains more than 1 row

```
IF UPDATE (status)
BEGIN

    update t
    set    ....
    from   inserted i
           inner join some_table t on i.somecol = t.anothercol
    where  t.status = 'Failure'

    update t
    set    ....
    from   inserted i
           inner join some_table t on i.somecol = t.anothercol
    where  t.status = 'Success'

    . . . . . -- other status value

END
```

Comment: Thanks squirrel for your response but I have need like (IF UPDATE (status)) action because I have to perform multiple action that not been possible by join or condition

Comment: the query will only execute when the status = 'Failure' just have multiple such query and check for diff value of `status`